# What is TrendMicroMarsAndroidSandbox?

Tags: android, crittercism

***A note to casual surfer***: if you don't have idea what Crittercism or TrendMicroMarsAndroidSandbox are, just pass on to questions you know something about and **don't downvote**. This is a valid question/issue.

I'm a [Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/) user and got a crash report which under Diagnostics for (device) Model says: "TrendMicroMarsAndroidSandbox".

I've never encountered "TrendMicroMarsAndroidSandbox" as an app or device, so the question:

**What is TrendMicroMarsAndroidSandbox?**

Is it a real device (with some sort of TrendMicro anti-virus sandbox for applications) or an emulator or what?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's this app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trendmicro.tmmspersonal

Mars : Mobile App Reputation Service

Comment: Seems sensible, @adamLee. This blog seems to address that, too: http://blog.trendmicro.com/beyond-anti-malware/ . Could you confirm it with a debug log maybe?

Comment: @Saran, if you can provide the debug log, I can try to confirm it.